# What's a good fullscreen launcher for the Gnome2 desktop?

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation, launcher

I like elementary' s Slingshot, but as you can see from [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C36ao.png), it doesn't correctly show all of my applications (you can see Synaptic on the Unity Launcher but not in Slingshot; generally all the apps in the Administration and Preferences menus are not featured). I tried lxlauncher in the past but I would like something that can be summoned with a hotkey. I know KDE has options under the form of widgets, but I'm a Gnome guy. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Are you sure it needs to be fullscreen? If not, I'd recommend something like Synapse or GNOME Do.

Comment: I know about those apps, I actually never tried them. I' ll give it a shot, even though I'm not sure a semantic launcher is what I'm looking for, I'd like something with little chrome - if any - as possible. Thanks for the contribution though!

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

gnome-do is a great tool, but like you said not quite what you're looking for? The only other things like you describe that I have seen are applets/plugins for docks such as Avant Window Navigator and Cairo Dock.